# XML Deserialization failing on DocType tag

Tags: c#, doctype, xmlserializer

I'm working on an integration with a third party application that sends us an XML message.  Their XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE theirObj SYSTEM "theirDTD-2.0.dtd">
<theirObj>
    <properties>
        <datasource>ThirdParty</datasource>
        <datetime>2009-03-05T14:45:39</datetime>
    </properties>
        <data>
          ...
        </data>
</theirObj>
```

I'm trying to deserialize it using the XmlSerializer:

```
public theirObj Deserialize(string message) {
            if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( message ) ) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException( "message" );
            }
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof(theirObj ) );

            TextReader textReader = new StringReader( message );

            using (XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader( textReader )) {
                object deserializedObject = xmlSerializer.Deserialize( xmlReader );

                theirObj ent = deserializedObject as theirObj ;

                if (ent == null) {
                    throw new InvalidCastException("Unable to cast deserialized object to an theirObj object. {0}".FormatInvariant( deserializedObject));
                }

                return ent;
            }
        }
}
```

I generated the objects using xsd.exe.

If I remove the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag then it deserializes fine.

Is there a way to get XmlSerializer to ignore the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag?

I know I could strip it out before passing it the XmlSerializer, but I'd rather not go to that level of XML manipulation if I don't have to.

Comment: Go get check this link, It works for me. [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228371/allow-net-webapi-to-disregard-doctype-declaration)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `XmlTextReader`, call [`XmlReader.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162475.aspx) and pass it an `XmlReaderSettings` object with [`DtdProcessing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.dtdprocessing.aspx) set to [`Ignore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.dtdprocessing.aspx):

```
TextReader textReader = new StringReader( message );
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore };

using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
```

**Note:** The `DtdProcessing` property was added in .NET 4.0. In .NET 3.5, you can instead set [`ProhibitDtd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.prohibitdtd.aspx) to `false` and [`XmlResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.xmlresolver.aspx) to `null`:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ProhibitDtd = false, XmlResolver = null };
```

Comment: Perfect!  That worked like a charm.  I was dreading having to strip the tag out (felt too much like a hack).

Answer (score 0):

DOCTYPE has no built-in XmlSerlization attributes. In fact, this is because the XML Serialization is element based rather than document based. I think you can use the following approach to skip DOCTYPE in your serialization:

```
public static String Serialize(object obj)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(theirObj));

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj);

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Then, you inject it back once the document has been deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the doctype

```
TextReader textReader = new StringReader( message );
XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
XDoc.Load(textReader);
XmlDocumentType XDType = XDoc.DocumentType;
XDoc.RemoveChild(XDType);

using (XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(XDoc)) {
                object deserializedObject = xmlSerializer.Deserialize( xmlReader );

                theirObj ent = deserializedObject as theirObj ;

                if (ent == null) {
                    throw new InvalidCastException("Unable to cast deserialized object to an theirObj object. {0}".FormatInvariant( deserializedObject));
                }

                return ent;
            }
```